# disappearing variables in DolphinDB database notebook

Tags: dolphindb

I find that if I work in DolphinDB notebook on the web, the variables would disappear after a while. Why is that? I also noticed that I don't have this problem if I work in DolphinDB GUI.

Answer (score 0):

If a web session is not active for 10 minutes or more, DolphinDB server will kill this session automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend coding in DolphinDB GUI or VSCode extension instead of DolphinDB notebook.